# Failed to connect Winsoc socket in Windows 2012 MSMQ

Tags: sockets, winsock, msmq, windows-server-2012

I have a website uses enterprise library to log using MSMQ trace listener. Site is creating logs. The logs are in MSMQ outgoing queues. However, queues are not being sent to remote computer. Message I get is

> Failed to connect Winsock socket. Address:IP=xx.xx.xx.xx

State is in "Waiting to Connect". The queue path I have as `queuePath="FormatName:DIRECT=OS:computername\Private$\private queuename"`

Am I missing anything? May be firewall rule? when I look at the firewall rule in destination computer, it allows the MSMQ Inbound TCP/UDP for all ports.

Comment: Enabling Remote Event Monitor (RPC-EPMAP) inbound rule in firewall fixed the issue I was getting. Now outgoing queue says it is connected to remote computer. However, I don't see any queue in remote computer under private queues. I also don't see queues in outgoing queues in source computer that means queues are being sent but not being logged in queue in destination computer. Looks like still missing to setup some rules in destination folder.

Comment: I am adding this because it might help someone out there and save time. Now private queue not receiving by destination computer is also solved. It was permission issue. I had to give Receive Message permission to two users - "Everyone" and "Anonymous Logon". After adding these two users, my destination computer started receiving private queue messages. To add permission, right click on the private queue name  you created. Go to security Tab, add the users.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling Remote Event Monitor (RPC-EPMAP) inbound rule in firewall fixed the issue I was getting. Now the state is Connected and Connection History is Connection is ready to transfer messages.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add I found that port 1801 which msmq port for allowing incoming traffic need to be opened.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/183293/how-to-configure-a-firewall-for-msmq-access